# Show Vim omnicomplete on certain characters instead of Ctrl-X Ctrl-O?

Tags: html, css, vim, editor, text-editor

In Vim 7, Ctrl-X Ctrl-O shows a list of possible values but I find this sequence of keys to be too long when I frequently use the autocomplete feature. For instance, in an HTML file, I'd like to see the list automatically popup after I type a < followed by one or two letters. In a CSS file, I'd like to see the list after I hit the ":" key. Is there a way to set this up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To activate the omnicompletion on typing a ":" you can use
the following mapping.

```
imap : :<c-x><c-o>
```

The disadvantage is that each time you press ":" omnicompletion will
be activated, even when typing ":" in comments or in any other context
in which you do not want omnicompletion.

I have mapped ctrl-space to active omnicompletion:

```
imap <c-space> <c-x><c-o>
```

This gives me the choice to activate omni whenever I need it.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Habi on this one.  It's better to specifically trigger omni-completion when you need it than to have it automatically triggered.  Omni-completion should be a tool to help you, not a crutch that you rely on.

Comment: I would say, just restrict it to the CSS filetype (as the only time you'll type : is when you want those options.

`au FileType css imap : :<c-x><c-o>`

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative that I found easier is just to press tab two times when you want autocomplete, and one time for regular tab.
Add the following line to your ~/.vimrc

```
imap <tab><tab> <c-x><c-o>
```

Comment: Looks great! Any idea on how to use the tab key to select the next choice as well (instead of ctrl-n)?

Comment: To use the tab key to launch omni completion, and also to select the next choice, add this to vimrc: `inoremap <tab> <c-r>=pumvisible() ? "\<lt>down>" : "\<lt>c-x>\<lt>c-o>"<cr>`